# JQuery prop function does not work to disabled a button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using JQuery function "prop" to change the state of a button to disabled for a while, when finish de process it usign the "prop" function again to enable the button.

But it doesn't work, and I don't know why. I have other JS files where it works fine, with the same example, only in this case it's doesn't work.

May be happen 'cause the function call is diferent, in other files it using JQuery to detect the event and call the function for the button and not using the "href" attribute to reference the function. But I don't guess for sure if this is the reason.

The button html:

```
<a type="button" class="btn btn-sky" id="btnFind" value="" href="javascript:getRegistros()">
   Buscar </a>
```

And the Javascript function:

```
function getRegistros() {
if ($("#formReg").valid()) {
  $("#btnFind").html("<i class='fa fa-refresh fa-spin'></i> Buscando");
  $("#btnFind").prop("disabled", true);
  .
  .
  .
   <<looking data>>
  .
  .
  .
  $("#btnFind").html("Buscar");
  $("#btnFind").prop("disabled", false);
 }
}
```

Any idea could help, thanks btw.

Comment: This might not be it, but i've never seen a <a type="button"> tag before. Have you tried just making it a <button type="button"> tag instead?

Comment: Yeah, anchors don't have a type, nor can they be disabled, and it's a misuse of the href attribute as you have it. An actual button element would be more appropriate.  Also, use event handlers in your script instead of putting JavaScript in your markup.

Comment: Ok many thanks to both. I don't use the button tag just on a whim

Comment: Also tried the .attr("disabled") function to disable the anchor button, but it disabled only in appearance, when it clicked it do again the function call.

It could sound like stupid question, but I wanted to be sure. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Html anchor tag  doesn't have type attribute. So, the better way to use button is either use `<button>` tag or `<input type="button">` tag for which you can use jquery prop method to set the property disabled to true/false. 
But if you want to use the same tag you need to change it as:
`<a type="button" class="btn btn-sky" id="btnFind" value="" href="#" onclick="getRegistros()">
   Buscar </a>`
you need to use `$("#btnFind").attr("disabled", true);` to set the attribute.

If you want that after disabling the button the function shouldn't be called you can modify the code as shown in the snippet below:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>demo</title>
<script>
   function getRegistros(el) {
  if(!$(el).hasClass("disabled")){
    $("#btnFind").html("<i class='fa fa-refresh fa-spin'></i> Buscando");
    $("#btnFind").attr("disabled", true);
    $("#btnFind").addClass("disabled");
   }
 } 
    </script>
    
    </head>
    <body>
       <a type="button" class="btn btn-sky" id="btnFind" value="" href="#" onclick="getRegistros(this)">
   Buscar </a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm tried the .attr("disabled", true) function to disable the anchor button, but it disabled only in appearance, when it clicked it do again the function call. 

 Thanks!

Comment: you can check my modified answer above if you want to stop the function calling once it is disabled you need to modify the code as explained above. because a disabled button can stop calling the event listeners but an anchor tag don't.